# get src of category image (using SF Taxonomy Thumbnail)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the SF Taxonomy Thumbnail plugin to add category images to my categories.

I am trying to use the src of a category image in a background-image within the style of a header element.

I can display the relevant category image on each individual category using the following:

```
echo get_term_thumbnail($wp_query->get_queried_object_id());
```

This returns the correct img tag however I need the src rather than the element. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`, it return an array (url, width, height, is_intermediate), or false, if there is no image available.

```
$term_thumbnail = get_term_thumbnail($wp_query->get_queried_object_id());

$size = 'medium';// choose the image size to get

$attachment_img_atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term_thumbnail, $size);

if ( $attachment_img_atts ) {
 ?>
<img src="<?php echo $attachment_img_atts[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $attachment_img_atts[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $attachment_img_atts[2]; ?>" />  
<?php 
}
```

More details [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

EDIT:

wp_get_attachment_image_url() returns an array with the url, width and height of the attachment id in parameter (see other that are optional and their default value), you only need $attachment_img_atts[0]; in your case and put it in the background-url.

```
    function se_40495669($post_id){
        $term_thumbnail = get_term_thumbnail($post_id);
        $size = 'large';// choose the image size to get
        $attachment_img_atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term_thumbnail, $size);

        if ( $attachment_img_atts ) {
              $url = $attachment_img_atts[0];
        }
        return $url;
    }
```

And use it in your code:

```
    style="background-image: url(<?php echo se_40495669($wp_query->get_queried_object_id()); ?>)";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wanted to be able to use the url of the category image such that style="background-image: url(<?php echo some_function($wp_query->get_queried_object_id()) ?>)"; Your method doesn't seem to return the url

Answer (score 0):

```
function expats_term_get_attachment(){
    $args = array( 
        'orderby'=> 'name', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'hide_empty' => true, 
        'exclude'=> array(), 
        'exclude_tree' => array(), 
        'include'=> array(), 
        'number' => '', 
        'fields' => 'all', 
        'slug'   => '', 
        'parent' => '', 
        'hierarchical' => true, 'child_of' => 0, 
        'childless' => false, 
        'get' => '', 
        'name__like' => '', 
        'description__like' => '', 
        'pad_counts' => false, 
        'offset' => '', 
        'search' => '', 
        'cache_domain' => 'core', );
}

    $taxonomy = 'category';
    expats_term_get_attachment();
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        $cat_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_term_thumbnail_id( $term->term_taxonomy_id ), '' );
        $cat_slug = $term->slug;
        $cat_name = $term->name;
?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="cat-image" style="background-url('<?php echo $cat_url; ?>');">
                <p><?php echo $cat_name; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```